# Rendering of [file] crashed

Tags: kdenlive

When I try to render something with Kdenlive, it says this:

Rendering of [file path] crashed

[gif @ [compute memory number]] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[swscaler @ [computer memory number]] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss

Comment: Which codec does your container/file contain? To find out you might install a little [helper](https://github.com/kanehekili/MediaInfoGui) I've written.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same or a similar issue using kdenlive 19.12.3. on Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2. The error says: "Crashed....no more csLADSPA plugins....Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead."      Kdenlive v19 worked fine several months ago. I just re-installed it after two later versions couldn't render. It's strange because v19 successfully rendered a short clip earlier today, but now it crashes every time.  I'm trying to render from edited MP4s to the same, an MP4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't address the root cause, but unchecking "parallel processing" before rendering solved the issue in my case